# Youtube video API onStateChange event cannot be used to change video

Tags: javascript, api, events, video, youtube

I want to use the onStateChange event provided by the Youtube API to listen to for the end of the video and then get a new video to play in the player. However, this does not seem to be possible for some reason.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) {
        console.log('done');
        goNext();
    }
}

function goNext() {
    player.loadVideoById('JBJ1VPBrCl0', 0, 'default');
}
```

I register the event handler like this

```
player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '530',
      width: '640',
      videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
```

Problem is: if I call my function goNext() manually, the video changes. If I wait for the video termination, the 'done' message is printed to the console, but the video does not change. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

I've put up a fiddle here. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/PHXY2/

Comment: I have managed to fix this by changing the goNext() function to this 

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(event.data === 0) {
            event.target.loadVideoById('JBJ1VPBrCl0', 0, 'default');
        }
    }

But I don't understand why my previous code did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, your fiddle example worked fine for me (after the video ends it automatically starts playing the "Short - Cat Meowing - Funny Cat Video - Red Laser" video ) Did you happen to have any YouTube-related browser extensions installed earlier? Some have been known to cause issues with the YT API.

Comment: I deactivated all my extensions, but the issue persists. However, I tried in Firefox and it works.

Apparently google chrome has an issue but it is not extension related

Comment: Hmm...I was running Chrome here earlier (on Win7 machine) just fine ( version 33.0.1750.154m )